# Magento - How to make new shipping address (additional) as default

Tags: magento, checkout

I developed a custom checkout module and is working fine. During checkout for the first when I enter new billing and shipping address, they are getting set as default billing and shipping address, which is fine. Now, I have a requirement, whenever a new shipping address is entered, this should become as default shipping address. Somehow, I cannot make this work. I have tried the following:

$shipdata is a array having the new address details.

```
$shipAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$shipAddress->addData($shipdata);
$shipAddress->setIsDefaultShipping(true);

if($this->getQuote()->getDefaultShipping()) {
   $this->getQuote()->setData('default_shipping', '');
   $this->getQuote()->addAddress($shipAddress);
}
$this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$this->getQuote()->save();
```

I also tried to add the following in the $shipdata

```
$shipdata['default_shipping'] = 1;
```

but also did not help.
Can some one help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an observer on the "customer_address_save_before" event. Setting the isDefaultShipping flag there will work. Only thing I don't know is checking whether you are in the checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

In the form that posts to the next page simply include a hidden input